# Initialize member function arguments as data members in c++

Tags: c++, class

When trying to implement a class like this

```
class sample{
    int a;
public:
    sample(int a = 0){
        this->a =a ;
    }
    void fun(int base = /*the value of a*/){
        // some function code
    }
};
```

I want to initialize the argument `base` of the function `fun` with the value of `a` (the data member of the class).

> Writing `int base = a` or `int base = this->a` doesn't work.

So, I thought I could overload the function this way.

```
void fun(void){
    fun(a);
}

void fun(int base){
    // some function code
}
```

This will actually work, but is there any better/smarter way to do the same thing? Because I have many other functions, I want to implement the same way. And I don't want to overload each of them.

Thanks.

Comment: trying to be smart or too lazy usually does not lead to better code. Your solution is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Sentinel values

This can be achieved via a "sentinel" value. If a particular integer is unused (such as `-1`), try:

```
void fun(int base = -1) {
    if (base == -1) {
        base = this->a;
    }

    // ...
}
```

---

### [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional)

Another way is to wrap the input up with an `std::optional`:

```
void fun(std::optional<int> base = std::nullopt) {
    if (!base) {
        base = this->a;
    }

    // Extract actual value by using *.
    int base_value = *base;

    // Use base_value.
    // ...
}
```

In the example above, `base_value` is the "default"-corrected `int` that you desired. A more elegant [alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67468540/initialize-member-function-arguments-as-data-members-in-c/67468660#comment119251754_67468655) is to use [`std::optional<T>::value_or`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/value_or) to extract the value:

```
void fun(std::optional<int> base = std::nullopt) {
    int base_value = base.value_or(this->a);

    // Use base_value.
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This is actually working, but I had a question. The type of `base` is `std::optional<int>` and the type of `this->a` is `int`. So, does `this->a` get type casted when assigning into `base`? Also, if you could add an edit that, the actual value is obtained using `*base`, it would be really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: There is no typecast -- instead, it uses one of the overloads for [`std::optional<T>::operator=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator%3D).

Answer (score 3):

You can make it explicit with [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional). Before that (or Boost.Optional or whatever), the usual solution would be to sacrifice a magic value that `base` could never legally take (such as `-1` in the other answer).

```
class sample{
    int a_;
public:
    sample(int a = 0) : a_(a) {}

    void fun(std::optional<int> base = std::nullopt){
        if (!base) base = a_;
        // some function code
    }
};
```

Or, as Jarod42 suggests, something like

```
    void fun(std::optional<int> base_opt = std::nullopt){
        int base = base_opt.value_or(a_);
        // some function code
    }
```

---

NB.

> Writing int base = a or int base = this->a doesn't work

Yeah, there *is* no instance at the point where the function is declared, and that's when the default expression is evaluated.

I was under the impression that `private` members, when they're inaccessible at the call site, would be prohibited - but that isn't correct. So the expression must be evaluated when the function is declared, with the function's own access and symbol visibility at that point, even though it is executed at the call site.

Comment: `base.value_or(a_);` might be interesting too.

Comment: Good idea, I added another possible usage.

Comment: *"Of course it doesn't - `a` is private"*, Wrong explanation: [Demo with public which won't work](https://godbolt.org/z/cGj1Wsh18) [Demo with private usage which works](https://godbolt.org/z/4MdeEnG5a)

Comment: Oh that's interesting, I didn't know that private members were considered accessible at the call site. I also forgot to mention that non-static members are prohibited of course, so I'll fix that.

Comment: Apologies for dealy in reply but your code seems to have a compilation error.
Please check this : https://onlinegdb.com/H1CJAet_d
I suppose it should be `std::nullopt` instead of `std::nullopt_t`.

Answer (score 0):

Overload of `fun` is simple and clean:

```cpp
class sample{
    int a;
public:
    sample(int a = 0){
        this->a =a ;
    }
    void fun(){
       fun(a);
    }
    void fun(int base){
        // some function code
    }
};
```